# dataSet = DataSet (datas[key]) and for featureValue in Feature((data[0].__len__()-1),data).get_values():

Tags: python

i keep getting this errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Program Data Set: 
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/fileHandling/ICTdataset/attributeSelection.py", line 89, in <module>
    dataSet = DataSet (datas[key])
  File "C:/Users/Admin/PycharmProjects/fileHandling/ICTdataset/attributeSelection.py", line 9, in __init__
    for featureValue in Feature((data[0].__len__()-1),data).get_values():
AttributeError: 'Feature' object has no attribute 'get_values'
```

Thanks for the answering because im new in python and trying to learn how o make decision tree.

This is the line 89 part:

```
datas = {"Program":WEATHER}
for key in datas:
    print(key,"Data Set: ")
    dataSet = DataSet (datas[key])
    print(dataSet)
    featuresInfoGain = {}
    for column in range(0, dataSet.get_data()[0].__len__()-1):
        feature = Feature(column, dataSet.get_data())
        dataSets = [DataSet for  i in range(feature.get_values().__len__())]
        i = 0
        for featureValue in feature.get_values():
            dataSets[i] = create_data_set(featureValue,column,dataSet.get_data())
            i + 1
```

this is where the line 9 is:

```
class DataSet:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self._data = data
        self._entropy = 0

        for featureValue in Feature((data[0].__len__()-1),data).get_values():
            self._entropy += self.minus_plog_2(featureValue.get_occurences()/(data.__len__()-1))
```

im trying to make a system that will find the best attribute to make decision trees. Thank You

Comment: What is Feature type? Is it pandas DataFrame?

Comment: its a class sir.
    def __init__(self, column, data):
        self._name = data[0][column]
        self._values = set()

        for row in range(1, data.__len__()):
            self._values.add(FeatureValue(data[row][column]))
        for featureValue in self._values:
            counter = 0;

Comment: for row in range (1, data.__len__()):
                if (featureValue.get_name() == data [row][column]):
                    counter += 1
                    featureValue.set_occurences(counter)

        def get_values(self): return self._values
        def get_name(self): return self._name
        def __str__(self): return self._name

Comment: ok. this class (Feature) have not that method (get_value). can you show Feature class code?

Comment: class Feature:
    def __init__(self, column, data):
        self._name = data[0][column]
        self._values = set()

        for row in range(1, data.__len__()):
            self._values.add(FeatureValue(data[row][column]))
        for featureValue in self._values:
            counter = 0;

Comment: for row in range (1, data.__len__()):
                if (featureValue.get_name() == data [row][column]):
                    counter += 1
                    featureValue.set_occurences(counter)

        def get_values(self): return self._values
        def get_name(self): return self._name
        def __str__(self): return self._name

Comment: this is the whole feature class sir